# The page always break when the height of column out of paper size

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

[This is my file html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Rqj.png)
when i wil print
[the row is break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOkL4.png)
when i use the header of table will show
[there was the line is erased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5R5m.png)

How to make the row is not break? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try to solve this with

```
<style>
    table { page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
</style>
```